# Query in Access using NOT LIKE

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-like

I am using a query as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE ([Material Description] Not Like "*LICENSE*" Or 
       [Material Description] Not Like "*LICENCE*");
```

However, this fetches me results having records with LICENCE or LICENSE in the Material Description field. Please advise as to what is that I am missing so that my query yields me result omitting the records containing these words in the Material Description field.

Comment: @Mackan: he included the * in the original post... the * however was used to make the text italic...

Comment: @luk2302 Ah, I understand. Will revert

Comment: In the original post it was "*LICENSE*" which will be "LICENSE" written italic if he does not use code tags - i miss edited as well thinking it was a misleading edit at first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you actually want is `AND` in between:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE ([Material Description] NOT LIKE '*LICENSE*' AND 
       [Material Description] NOT LIKE '*LICENCE*');
```

You will currently select the record "LICENSE" because it does **NOT** contain "LICENCE" and the record "LICENCE" because it does **NOT** contain "LICENSE".
The records you currently really exclude are the ones which contain "LICENCE" **AND** "LICENSE", probably not many ;). That little confusion arises from the usage of Or in combination with Not.

Another way to achieve the same goal would be to move the `NOT` in front of the `OR`ed condition:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE NOT ([Material Description] LIKE '*LICENSE*' OR
           [Material Description] LIKE '*LICENCE*');
```

That way it is a little bit clearer what you actually want to achieve.
This will read `NOT (A OR B)` as opposed to `(NOT A) OR (NOT B)` and has very different truth table:

```
A  B  |  (  ~  A  )  &  (  ~  B  )
----------------------------------
0  0  |     1  0     1     1  0     
0  1  |     1  0     0     0  1     
1  0  |     0  1     0     1  0     
1  1  |     0  1     0     0  1 


A  B  |  ~  (  A  |  B  )
-------------------------
0  0  |  1     0  0  0     
0  1  |  0     0  1  1     
1  0  |  0     1  1  0     
1  1  |  0     1  1  1
```

Your truth table would look like

```
A  B  |  (  ~  A  )  |  (  ~  B  )
----------------------------------
0  0  |     1  0     1     1  0     
0  1  |     1  0     1     0  1     
1  0  |     0  1     1     1  0    
1  1  |     0  1     0     0  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check your conditions.

- The first condition of the statements gets all records with [Material
  Description] doesn't contains "LICENSE". So I gives you also the
  records witch contains "LICENCE".
- The second condition gives you all records with [Material
  Description] doesn't contains "LICENCE". So you'll get records with
  "LICENSE" too.
- Because you use an OR-operation the records from both conditions will
  be combined.

The result is that you get all the records from your table.

Answer (score 1):

Without the wildcard character (`*` in MS Access, `%` in most reasonable databases), `like` behaves like the `=` operator. If you want to exclude records where these words are contained somewhere in the relevant field, just surround it with wildcards:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TableName 
WHERE  ([Material Description] NOT LIKE '*LICENSE*' OR 
        [Material Description] NOT LIKE '*LICENCE*');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you need with a single `Like` pattern which includes a character range:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE [Material Description] Not Like '*LICEN[CS]E*';
```

That means exclude rows whose *[Material Description]* values contain *LICEN*, followed by either *C* or *S*, followed by *E*.  At least to me, its meaning is clearer than the combination of 2 `Not Like` conditions.

It would be even simpler if you can broaden the scope to *LICEN*, followed by any single character, followed by *E*.  It that is suitable, use `?` to represent any single character:

```sql
WHERE [Material Description] Not Like '*LICEN?E*';
```

Comment: well, that is nice as well, I was a little too focused on the boolean logic :P